# Pushing objects into javascript array performance weirdness

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, canvas, requestanimationframe

I'm creating a flock simulation using html5 canvas and I'm trying to squeeze every bit of performance out of javascript. I've noticed a "weird" performance boost/blow depending on when/where I add boids to the system.

If I fill the boids array with 400 objects first and then start the animation (using requestAnimationFrame) I get a very decent 40-50fps in Chrome and Safari, and around 30fps in Firefox.

However if the boids array gets filled with objects (400 of them again) during the animation (for example by dragging on the screen), than no matter the browser the performance always drops to about 15-20fps.

In both cases I use `boids.push( new Boid() );` to fill the boids array. In the first case I do it from within a for loop and in the second I do it from the mouseDown event handler.

Any idea why the performance of the first would be so much better?

You can find both of the examples here:
[Version A](http://1da86cfb8c73d5ce7039-8a2fd7fd1acccb4bcb6caea58ae6d4a8.r44.cf3.rackcdn.com/flock-a.html) and [Version B](http://1da86cfb8c73d5ce7039-8a2fd7fd1acccb4bcb6caea58ae6d4a8.r44.cf3.rackcdn.com/flock-b.html)

Comment: Could the boids just be less evenly distributed in the second version, and therefore cause each boid to have more neighbours to consider? Does the second version eventually smooth out to a higher frame rate?

Comment: Both of them eventually even out in terms of how many neighbours each boid sees. The version B doesn't get smoother through time. My assumption was that there something with garbage collection and array re-sizing, but it doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: For performances 1) never create an object out of the init (no new, no {} ) do everything on place. 2) for the flock update, use a rotating *index*, not array. Do not compute sum each time : substract current, randomize it, increase the index, rotate index if required. You'll save a great amount of time and g.c.

Comment: On a verrrry quick look: you have some heavy methods on your boids pseudo-class.  You might move those methods to the boids prototype.  That way each new boid instance doesn't need its own (heavy) copy of the methods. Instead, every instance shares the prototype methods. BTW, your app has very different performance levels across browsers: Chrome does well, FF is OK, IE quickly degrades to 10-15fps in both versions.  Again....a very quick look :-)

Comment: GameAlchemist, I don't want to sound to silly, but could you elaborate on the rotating index instead of array?

Comment: @Peter: my explanation was surely too short. Have var currWander = new Vector() a class private member initialized with sum of wanderBuffer. Have wanderIndex=0; change wander() name to updateWander(). In updateWander() method : substract item=wanderBuffer[wanderIndex] from currWander , then randomize it item.x=random()...item.y=...; then add item's new value to currWander, then 'rotate' the index : wanderIndex=(wanderIndex+1)% wanderBuffer.length; this way you avoid moost costly shift/push, act on-place, and save ops. *Now* you'd be silly not to get it. (!!!!Just kidding :-) :-) !!!)

Comment: @Peter: was i clear enough ? A little hard in 600 chars... If you make a fiddle, i'll update it, that might be a better way to explain. Don't forget to put @ in front of people's name so they get notified.

Answer (score 0):

If your `reuestAnimationFrame` callback execution takes longer than ~10ms fps drops and you will janks. So the first method probably meets that budget or sometimes slightly takes more since you are not getting ~60fps; but the second method definitely exceed the ~10ms on that frame and the browser have to skip 2-3 frames to complete the execution of that callback therefor you get ~20fps;

Check out this article on google web fundamentals [Rendering Performance](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering#60fps_and_device_refresh_rates)